# How to change these codes to execute faster

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < clear_no7.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lst_cnacld.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        if (lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Code"].ToString() == clear_no7.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString())
        {
            clear_no7.Rows[i]["Route"] = lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Route"];
        }
        else if ((Convert.ToInt32(lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Code"]) / 10).ToString() == clear_no7.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString())
        {
            clear_no7.Rows[i]["Route"] = lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Route"];
        }
        else if ((Convert.ToInt32(lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Code"]) / 100).ToString() == clear_no7.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString())
        {
            clear_no7.Rows[i]["Route"] = lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Route"];
        }
        else if ((Convert.ToInt32(lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Code"]) / 1000).ToString() == clear_no7.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString())
        {
            clear_no7.Rows[i]["Route"] = lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Route"];
        }
    }
}
```

This code works correctly but take too long time to execute. How can I change them to execute faster?

Comment: what is the type of `clear_no7`? Is it a `DataTable`? You need to provide us more details

Comment: You could start by fetching data from the table once, store it in a local variable and then use it. You also have alot of conversions, which take time.

Comment: Use a profiler and **measure** to avoid that you´re overevaluating the effect on your performance. Anyway you should consider to extract variables for expressions that you execute multiple times, in your case `lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["..."]`.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be in code review?

Comment: at least you could break the loop when if condition is met.

Comment: The first thing I'd do would be to assign `lst_cnacld.Rows[j]["Code"]` and `clear_no7.Rows[i]["Code"].ToString()` to variables, at the beginning of the `for` loop. Also, have you tried using `Parallel.For`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba. Parallel.For can increase performance, but if used wrongly/in the wrong place, it could also decrease performance. The overhead involved with creating a new parallel/thread is very high. Personally, I don't think Parallel.For is the place to use for something this "light". I only use it when you have several heavy-fight tasks that take long to finish, to perform.

Comment: A better algoritm is to add the items to lists and sort them. Keep an index variable for each list and increase it when the value is _smaller than_ the other value. If it is greater, increase the index of the other list. If the values match...

Comment: @WynDiesel true, if not used properly it can decrease performance. In this particular case is hard to tell, it might be worth a try if the `DataTable`s are big.

Comment: yes. lst_cnacld and clear_no7 are datatable and both have more than 10 thousand rows

Comment: Perhaps the best approach, if possible, is to look at how do you load these tables and see if it is possible to change the query statement

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test the code without any test data, or knowing what your types are, but I would do this :

I would create class to reflect the type what I'm, working with, like this :

```
public class TempType
{
    public  string Route { get; set; }
    public  int Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would avoid using datatables, and have a list of classes, like this :

```
var listA = new List<TempType>();
var listB = new List<TempType>();

foreach (var typeA in listA)
{
    foreach (var typeB in listB)
    {
        if (typeA.Code == typeB.Code
            || typeA.Code / 10 == typeB.Code
            || typeA.Code / 100 == typeB.Code
            || typeA.Code / 1000 == typeB.Code
         )
         {
             typeB.Route = typeA.Route;
         }
    }
}
```

You also have some strainge business logic going on there, but I'll just put that in as is.

Comment: While I don't disagree on the use of a specific type for your data, this answer doesn't consider the time required to fill the two lists with the actual data from the tables.

Comment: @Steve, fair comment. I don't know how he's populating (what I assume to be) dataTable.